# How to concatenate individual quote marks in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, lxml, quotes

I'm trying to incorporate an lxml method into another function that I'm building.

The lxml takes a string wrapped in double quote marks as input. Within that string lies another term wrapped in single quote marks. Like this:

```
root.findall(".//*[@name='File Name']")
```

However, I want to pass the value within the single quotes (`'File Name'`) from the argument of a function.

Like so:

```
def foo(bar):
    root.findall(".//*[@name="+bar+"]")
```

However, I can only get it to work by entering the `bar` arg with both double and single quotes, like this: `"'bar'"`.

How can I configure it so that one only needs to write `'bar'`?

I've tried `+"\""+bar+"\""+` but that didn't work.

EDIT: I've figured out one method:

```
def foo(bar):
    atr = '"'+atr+'"'
    root.findall(".//*[@name="+bar+"]")
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking. I think this is what you want:

```
def foo(bar):
    root.findall(".//*[@name='{}']".format(bar))
```

That means if you call `foo("XYZ")`, it will call `root.findall(".//*[@name='XYZ']")`.

Comment: do you mean `{}` instead of `%s`?

Comment: Doh, still thinking in `printf`-mode.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can change the `foo()` function to include the single quote marks in the lxml `findall()` function call , like -

```
def foo(bar):
    root.findall(".//*[@name='" + bar + "']")
```

If you want to escape single quotes you can do that by using `\'` . Example -

```
>>> '\'bar\''
"'bar'"
```